What are dungeon coins for?
I've tried the new phantom Dungeon game and have received a bunch of Dungeon Coins, what do they do, also similarly: what do the Notes do?

I read with them you can buy stuff in an Shop in the phantom Dimension.

oh i thought i put Dungeon Coins?
